# Where do I get more mannequins?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I got a mannequin in the latest for putting clothes on it and such. Can you get another one? If so how? I tried to check if you can get another one by asking Sable but I got nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 4 mannequins that you can get in the game and the requirements are as follows:

- Purchase 51 items of clothing at Able Sisters and Mabel will give this to you
- Befriend Sable and she'll give you this after talking to her frequently
- Purchase at least one item on 31 different days from Labelle
- Receive from Gracie

Note that if you accidentally sell one of these, you can never get it back! Each character gets 4, so you'd presumably be able to start another resident to unlock another should you accidentally sell one.

However, you cannot trade mannequins between players in any way, so if you were indeed to accidentally delete one, you'd only have access to the mannequin on your other resident. Mannequins cannot be dropped and when attempting to attach one to a letter, I could not, as you can see below:

[image: mannequin]

Comment: Can you get more from other players?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot No, they're not tradeable at all. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

Grase will give you one when its your first time there in the t and t emporium after spending 100000 at the super t and t

Bells then after you spent 70000 you have to pass at least four fashion items, then buy 1 clothing from her. Then she will say "we have a discount". That's how you earn a maniqun

Comment: I think this might be from an older game.